# NotFoundHttpException Laravel 4

Tags: php, exception, laravel, laravel-4

I have a problem with my app on the server.

When I access it through various links, it works. But, when I put the URL to the same site in my browser, I get a `NotFoundHttpException`. What I have detected in the message of the exception are the following problems:

```
REDIRECT_URL    /app/public//login
REQUEST_URI     /app/public//login
```

I do not understand why it adds two slashes (`//`) after `public` instead of one (`/`).

The code for my file `route.php` is:

```
 Route::get('login', 'UserController@get_index');
```

And, the code for my Controller is:

```
public function get_index()
{
    return View::make('admin.login');
}
```

Comment: And your programming question is? Or are you just asking how to configure Laravel4? If so, I think the vendor offers better support resources.

Comment: please post your view code

Answer (score 1):

I think changing the naming convention to the one laravel uses will fix this problem.

Do this in your routes:

```
Route::get('login', 'UserController@getIndex');
```

and this in the controller:

```
public function getIndex()
{
    return View::make('admin.login');
}
```